# How do Promises change the use of functions

Tags: javascript, promise

I am having trouble finding a use for Promises.  Wouldn't these 2 approaches below work the same exact way?  Since the `while` loop in `loopTest()` is synchronous, `logStatement()` function wouldn't run until it's complete anyways so how would the the 2nd approach be any different ..wouldn't it be pointless in waiting for it to `resolve()` ?

**1st approach:**

```
function loopTest() {
   while ( i < 10000 ) {
       console.log(i)
       i++
   })
}


function logStatement() {
     console.log("Logging test")
}

loopTest();
logStatement();
```

**2nd approach:**

```
function loopTest() {

   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      while ( i < 10000 ) {
          console.log(i)
          i++
          if (i === 999) {
           resolve('I AM DONE')
          }
      })
   });
   
}


function logStatement() {
     console.log("Logging test")
}

loopTest().then(logStatement());
```

Comment: Promises are typically used for asynchronous work in conjunction with `async/await` syntax.

Comment: Promises with synchronous code don't make any sense - they're for asynchronous code. Also, there is a slight difference between the above two snippets. In the secon, anything lines after the final one will happen before the `console.log()`, because of the use of promises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promises don't make anything asynchronous,¹ so you're right, there's no point to using a promise in the code you've shown.

The purpose of promises is to provide a standard, composable means of observing the result of things that are *already* asynchronous (like ajax calls).

There are at least three massive benefits to having a standardized way to observe the results of asynchronous operations:

- We can have standard semantics for consuming individual promises, rather than every API defining its own signature for callback functions. (Does it signal error with an initial parameter that's `null` on success, like Node.js? Does it call the callback with an object with a success flag? Or...)
- We can have standard ways of composing/combining them, such as `Promise.all`, `Promise.race`, `Promise.allSettled`, etc.
- We can have syntax to consume them with our usual control structures, which we have now in the form of `async` functions and `await`.

But again, throwing a promise at a synchronous process almost never does anything useful.²

---

¹ One *very* small caveat there: The handler functions to attach to a promise are always triggered asynchronously, whether the promise is already settled or not.

² Another small caveat: Sometimes, you have a synchronous result you want to include in a composition operation (`Promise.all`, etc.) with various asynchronous operations. In that case, wrapping the value in a promise that's instantly fulfilled is useful — and in fact, all the standard promise combinators (`Promise.all`, etc.) do that for you, as does `await`.

Comment: FWIW, I go into promises in a fair bit of detail in Chapter 8 of my recent book *JavaScript: The New Toys*, and I go into `async`/`await` in detail in Chapter 9. Links in my profile if you're interested.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer.  To you point `The purpose of promises is to provide a standard, composable means of observing the result of things that are already asynchronous (like ajax calls).`, isn't a `fetch` already a Promise so if I had a `fetch` inside a function, I could just return the `fetch`.  What would I need to a wrap a Promise around?  That's the part that I don't understand

Comment: @MauirceA - If you're using `fetch`, you *already* have a promise (the one `fetch` gives you as its return value), so you wouldn't have any reason to wrap a promise around it. You'd probably chain off that promise, though. For instance, suppose you're getting some data from a server. `fetch("/the/data")` gives you a promise that's fulfilled with a `Response` object on success, but your `getTheData` function probably wants to fulfill its promise with the data, not a `Response` object. So you chain off it:

Comment: `function getTheData() { return fetch("/the/data").then(r => if (!r.ok) { throw new Error("HTTP error " + r.status); } return r.json(); }); }` The `.then` chains off the promise. If an error occurs ("rejection"), that passes right through your code untouched, but success ("fulfillment") is channelled to your `then` callback, where you can check that the HTTP operation succeeded and then read and return the body of the response.

Comment: (`fetch` slightly irritates me as an example because unfortunately [in my view], it only rejects its promise on *network* errors, not *HTTP* errors. So you have to have that check of the `ok` property on the `Response` object, and that obscures the value of promises when you use it as an example. More about that...feature...of the `fetch` API on my anemic blog: http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html)

Comment: Just for completeness, `getTheData` as an `async` function: `async function getTheData() { const r = await fetch("/the/data"); if (!r.ok) { throw new Error("HTTP error " + r.status); } return r.json(); }` Note that neither `getTheData` I've shown throws a synchronous error (unless `fetch` is missing or something), they only return a promise and (later) reject it if an error occurs.

Comment: Thanks again, this is great.  Yea, I am aware of the `catch` with `fetch`.  I was told to just check `http` status responses to see if it was successful or not.   I just posted an answer here which I think clears up my understanding in the use of Promises -- does that make sense now?

Answer (score 0):

There's no point in what you are doing, because your function body is just a blocking loop.

To get a benefit from Promises, use it with APIs that do something with IO, such as a HTTP request, or reading a file from disk.

These APIs all traditionally used callbacks, and are now mostly Promise based.

Anything function that uses a Promise-based function, should itself also be Promise-based. This is why you see a lot of promises in modern code, as a promise only has to be used at 1 level in a stack for the entire stack to be asynchronous in nature.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a better example of how Promises are used?  This is all I can think of to make it show use to me:

**Version 1**

```
function getData() {

   fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
   .then(data => data.json())
   .then(json => console.log(json))
  
}


function logInfo() {
     console.log("i am a logger")
}

getData()
logInfo()

// "I am a logger"
//  {"test": "json"}
```

**Version 2**

```
function getData() {

   return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
   .then(data => data.json())
   .then(json => console.log(json))
  
}


function logInfo() {
     console.log("i am a logger")
}

getData().then(logInfo);
// "{"test": "json"}
// "I am a logger"
// waits for API result to log _then_ logInfo is run , which makes a log statement
```

Comment: Yes, that's a better use for promises. The headline is: they're useful for asynchronous, not synchronous, operations, as others have noted above with their answers.

Comment: Further reading: I have an extensive [guide to Promises](https://mitya.uk/articles/javascript-promises-part-1) if you want to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

There's definitely benefits to using Promises but that's only in certain scenarios where their usage would seem viable.

Your example could represent what would happen when you retrieve data from an external source synchronously, it would block the thread preventing further code from executing until the loop terminates (I explain below why exactly that happens) - wrapping it in a promise gives no different output in that the thread is still being blocked and when the next message in the queue has to be processed, it gets processed like normal right after it ends.

However an implementation similar to this could achieve a while loop running in a non-blocking manner, just an idea (don't mean to derail this topic with setInterval's implementation):

```js
let f = () => {
  let tick = Date.now;
  let t = tick();
  let interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (tick() - t >= 3000) {
      console.log("stop");
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 0);
};
f()
console.log("start");
```

Basically the time is checked/handled in a separate thread in the browser and the callback is executed every time the time specified runs out while the interval hasn't been cleared, after the call stack becomes empty (so UI function isn't affected) and the current executing function terminates/ends or after other functions above it in the stack finish running. I don't know about the performance implications of doing something like this but I feel like this should only be used when necessary, since the callback would have to be executed very frequently (with 0 timeout, although it's not guaranteed to be 0 anyway).

#### why it happens

I mainly want to clarify that while the handler functions will be scheduled to be executed asynchronously, every message in the queue has to be processed completely before the next  one and for the duration your while loop executes, no new message can be processed in the event queue so it would be pointless to involve Promises where the same thing would happen without them.

So basically the answer to:

> wouldn't it be pointless in waiting for it to resolve() ?

is yes, it would be pointless in this case.